# How to make the alarm clock only go off on Monday and Tuesday?

Tags: windows-phone-7

There is a built-in alarm clock in windows phone 7.5 (mango), which can set the clock only repeat on specific time (ex. Monday,Tuesday....). I want implement the same function, but as far as i know, the properties of "alarm"/"reminder" didn't give me enough support for this. So i wonder if any one can help me on this ? appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the BeginTime of Alarm to the next monday and the RecurrenceType to Weekly

Comment: Could you give me some details?